# How to check if the field exists in firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am checking whether the Boolean field called `attending` exists, however I am not sure how to do that.

Is there a function such as `.child().exists()` or something similar that I could use?

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("Events")
    .document(ID)
    .collection("Users")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()){
                    attending = document.getBoolean("attending");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
  if(task.isSuccessful()){
    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()){
       if (document.exists()) {
          if(document.getBoolean("attending") != null){
             Log.d(TAG, "attending field exists");
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#exists()):

> `public boolean exists ()`
>
> Returns
> true if the document existed in this snapshot.

Comment: I think OP is asking about how to check the existence of a Field inside a document, not a document itself.

Comment: @DanielSaito Yes, but you cannot only retrieve a field alone. You can only retrieve a document, so this is the best way, get the document then check if the field is null.

Comment: yeah, but I think OP is talking after get the document, doing the `doc[index].get(field)` of a list of documents where some docs have this `field` and other don't, I think is a good example that converges to the same error that OP is struggling haha, sorry if I'm not very clear in my explanations.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing now is correct - you have to read the document and examine the snapshot to see if the field exists.  There is no shorter way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve it or you may have resolved already, this for any one searches for solution.

As per the documentation:

```
CollectionReference citiesRef = db.collection("cities");

Query query = citiesRef.whereNotEqualTo("capital", false);
```

This query returns every city document where the capital field exists with a value other than false or null. This includes city documents where the capital field value equals true or any non-boolean value besides null.

*For more information* : https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/order-limit-data#java_5

Answer (score 0):

I use following boolean method may be someone else can

```
for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()){
    if(document.contains("attending")){
           attending = document.getBoolean("attending");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution so what I do is a try - catch (sorry Flutter / Dart, not java):

```
  bool attendingFieldExists = true;
  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = 
  // your Document Query here
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance 
      .collection('collection')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
      .get();
  // trying to get "attending" field will throw an exception
  // if not existing
  try {
    documentSnapshot.get("attending");
  } catch (e) {
    attendingFieldExists = false;
    print("oops.. exception $e");
  }
```

Then you can adapt the code you want to apply depending on `attendingFieldExists`.
I'm new to Flutter / Dart so not sure this is the best way to handle this.. but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

instead of
documentSnapshot.get("attending");
do this
**documentSnapshot.ContainsField("attending");**

If the field exists it will return **true** else returns **false**.

Answer (score -3):

```
You can check firestore document exists using this,

CollectionReference mobileRef = db.collection("mobiles");
 await mobileRef.doc(id))
              .get().then((mobileDoc) async {
            if(mobileDoc.exists){
            print("Exists");
            }
        });
```

Comment: of what I understood, OP is asking about a field inside a doc, not a doc itself, test if a field exists inside a doc. I have the same issue.