# How can show "no data available" message if there will be not data available in snapshot from firestore in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a stream Builder that collect data from firestore.
sometimes with the new user can happen that some fields are still missing because of a new user.
I am trying this way: `${snapshot.data.docs[index]['review'] ?? 'No data available'}`
but nothing returns error it doesnt work.
here the full code:

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Consultant').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 60),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final profile = snapshot.data.docs;
              return Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                    Text(
                                    snapshot.data.docs[index]['nickName'],
```

I just want to substite the field if it is missing or null

Comment: please add some code snippet if possible ?

Comment: Text(
                    snapshot.data.docs[index]['review'].toString() == null ||
                        snapshot.data.docs[index]['review'].toString() == ""
                        ? "No Data Available"
                        : snapshot.data.docs[index]['review'].toString() 
              ),

Comment: you can try this may be it will work

Comment: No it doesnt work

Comment: please add some code snippet so more clear

Comment: code edited. as you can see I need to substite the field in case of missing or null

Comment: `snapshot.data.docs[index]['nickName'] ?? 'No data available'` should work unless it's an empty `String` or `snapshot.data.docs` is empty.

Comment: yes and If it is an empty String or missing?

Comment: I think that also the answers from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58180481/how-to-check-if-the-field-exists-in-firestore) shows good logic that can also be implemented in Dart and the first answer has also a good solution.