# Firebase - checking if field exits

Tags: javascript, firebase

In my firebase DB I have:

A `User` model and a field called `username`.

This username could either `exist` or be `""` When I say exist I mean that that field might not exist under the User 'yet'.

Im doing a check:

```
if (username || username != "")
    //show some stuff here
```

if the username field `DOES NOT` exist the above still `shows some stuff`

if the field doesn't exist when I log it it comes back as `undefined`

I have tried this:

```
if (username != undefined || username != "")
    //show some stuff here
```

The above also `shows some stuff`

Im trying to have it so if the username `exists` and `isNot` an `empty string` then `show stuff`

Comment: look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58180481/how-to-check-if-the-field-exists-in-firestore

Comment: at this point I have all the User pulled down and am passing it down into another component

Answer (score 0):

If any field is missing then it's undefined for sure. That `if-else` statement should work:

```js
const data = snapshot.val()
const username = data.username

if (username) {
  console.log("username is present")
} else {
  console.log("Username is absent")
}
```

I cannot see where that 'username' is coming from. If the above still doesn't work then please share the complete code so we can check if there's any mistake apart from the provided snippet in question.